# Simple Extension Creation One error a:4:{i:0;s:60:"Module "Magentostudy_News" requires module "Mage_adminhtml".";i:1;s:772:"#0

Tags: extensions

I Create a simple extension. It can Be Error.
**a:4:{i:0;s:60:"Module "Magentostudy_News" requires module "Mage_adminhtml".";i:1;s:772:"#0**

I Create Folder In local/Magentostudy and local/News

My app/etc/modules create Magentostudy_News.xml file  code here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
/** 
* Module initial config
* @author Magento
-->
<config>
        <modules>
            <Magentostudy_News>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_adminhtml/>
            </depends>
            </Magentostudy_News>

        </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `Mage_adminhtml` with `Mage_Adminhtml`. (Capital A in Adminhtml) and it should work.

Comment: THank It's Really Work

Answer (score 0):

Also You another issue with folder location

`app/code/community/Magentostudy/News` as you define your `codePool community`

Comment: If we can Create in our local folder that what can be issue create? can you just explain i don't know.

Comment: just change code pool <codePool>community</codePool> to <codePool>local</codePool>

Comment: Thank @amit bera

Answer (score 0):

local/Magentostudy and local/News

Magentostudy is the Namespace and News is the Module . So why did you created different folder . Its should be as follows.

local/Magentostudy/News.

As you used the codePool as a community it should be

community/Magentostudy/News.